# django "admin.site.register(...)" only for superuser

Tags: django, admin, backend, root

I would like to show a model in the admin backend only to the super user but not to the staff users, is it possibile?

example:

```
check which user is logged
if superuser

admin.site.register(model_1)
admin.site.register(model_2)
admin.site.register(model_3)
...

if staff_user

admin.site.register(model_1)   #show only one model in the admin
```

thank you

Answer (score 4):

It cannot work that way. Your `admin.py` module is imported and evaled once at process startup, not each time the process handles a request (hopefully else it would be painfully slow). The solution is to use django's permissions system : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: thank you bruno, I'm working on a system for managing products in a database. A user login, insert some products and then there is a public view to show them to the non-logged user. In this case is better to give the user the staff privileges or to create a custom backend for him? My goal is to scale the system to let any user login, insert products and manage them. thank you

Comment: Really depends on who your users are and how complex the backend is. If you only have a couple tech-savy users and the default (or almost default) admin works fine for your needs then just make them staff. For anything else I go for a custom backend. Given your last statement, you definitly want a custom backend IMHO.

Comment: my problem is that I need some nested inlines with dgango admin I cannot show more than one nested inline in a single view. I would like to have a single view in which the staff user manage all data about the products. –

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to achieve that is to create 2 admin sites, one for admins, another for staff. Consider below example with HRs and Root admins:

1. In `admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from core.models import CV

User = get_user_model()

def has_superuser_permission(request):
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_superuser

# Only superuser can access root admin site (default)
admin.site.has_permission = has_superuser_permission

class HRAdminSite(AdminSite):
    """HR admin page definition"""
    site_header = "HR Admin"

hr_admin_site = HRAdminSite(name='hr_admin')

# available only to super_users
@admin.register(User)
class RootUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

# available to both types of admins hr (is_staff) and root (is_superuser)
@admin.register(CV)
@admin.register(CV, site=hr_admin_site)
class CVAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

2. In `urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from core.admin import hr_admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path("root/", admin.site.urls),
    path("hr/", hr_admin_site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Group and assign it with your staff user and assign permissions to that group. Only Modules and permissions your assign to that group is able to see staff user other not.